# Connection to SQL Database

Tags: sql, vb.net

I am Making connection to Sql Database and in one connection i am changing my query many 
times,This is the basic structure of my code.The structure works fine.

I have Following Questions

1) Is this the right method of sending different Query to Sql Database.

2) Will this cause any memory leaks or error.

```
dim conn

set conn=CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

With conn
.Provider = "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0"
.ConnectionString ="Data Source=C:\MAP_sample.xls;" & "Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;"
.Open
End With

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

Query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] where StateName='ABC'"   

rs.Open  Query,conn

rs.close
```

CHANGE THE QUERY

```
Query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] where ID='321'"   

rs.Open  Query,conn
rs.close
```

change the query

```
Query = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] where NAME='SMITH'"   

rs.Open  Query,conn
rs.close

Set rs = nothing

conn.close
Set conn = nothing
```

Comment: You should consider using `using` blocks to handle resource acquisition and disposal e.g. closing connection is done by `using` and you don't need to call the `close` method explicitly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looks like classic ASP with visual basic.

1. It is one of the possible variants to send queries, it is not bad, a little bit [boilerplate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boilerplate_code), as suggestion - try to re-factor it into separate class or functions
2. No, it will no cause memory leaks or errors as you're calling [close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675814%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

> You can later call the Open method to re-establish the connection to the same, or another, data source.

the only problem with this approach comes when you need to have 2 recordset opened at the same time

if you speak about general code readability - it is better to use meaningful variable names